# UWP ListView Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, uwp

I am going to drag an item from a `ListView` to drop a box to process something.

In this case, I am not able to get selected `ListView` item. Selected Index/Items always returns `-1/null`.

Note: I am able to get selected listview item when using SelectionChanged. 
But not able to get drop event. Please advise.

The XAML source:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvMaster" CanDragItems="True" SelectionChanged="lvMaster_SelectionChanged" />

<Grid AllowDrop="True" Drop="Drop_Event" DragOver="DragOver_Event">        
</Grid>
```

The C# source:

```
private void Drop_Event(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    lvObj = new ListView();
    ListView)sender; 
}

private void DragOver_Event(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;          
    DragUIOverride.IsCaptionVisible = true;
    DragUIOverride.IsContentVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: You want to drag item from ListView to Grid and want to know wich item it is? Do I understand it correctly? Why do you need selectem item?

Comment: Yes. Correct. I need a selected item.

Comment: Because, i want to pass the id of selected item.

Comment: I want to know the what item is selected.

Comment: Then you need to set handler for DragCompleted on Item (not containers). Within this handler sender will be your item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register [DragItemsStarting event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.dragitemsstarting.aspx) or [DragItemsCompleted event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.dragitemscompleted.aspx) for your listview, then in its handler method, you could get all items you dragged.

```
private void SourceListView_DragItemsCompleted(ListViewBase sender, DragItemsCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var cc = args.Items;
}
```

Please refer to the official [Drag and Drop sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop/cs/Scenario1_ListView.xaml.cs#L74) for more details.

Please