# How to move List View Item between List Views with drag and drop when the List Views are created with a click of a button? UWP C#

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, drag-and-drop, listviewitem

I have an Universal Windows Platform Application in which there's an add button to create a List View, so there **aren't any list views on start**. You can later add List View Items to the created (added) List Views.

Here's the application with 2 ListViews added with the bottom add button and 1 ListViewItem added in each of them:

[image: The application with 2 ListViews added and 1 ListViewItem added in each of them]

**I need to be able to move one List View Item from one created List View (List 0) to another one (List 1) using drag and drop.**

How to handle the drag and drop events if the List Views are created in the app and are not on start?

Comment: Maybe you will find some useful information under the following link, where drag and drop in general regarding listview is mentioned?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398742/uwp-listview-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `CanDragItems` property on the first ListView and the `AllowDrop` property on the second ListView. Then you need to handle the `DragItemsStarting` event in the first listview and handle the `TargetListView_Drop` event in the second listview.

There is an official UWP sample in Github: [Drag and Drop](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop). You could download it and try the sample to see how it is implemented. The listview in the sample does not define the listview item in the Xaml.