# WinUI3 ListView InsertionMark functionality with C++/WinRT

Tags: uwp, winui-3, c++-winrt

Is there a function similar to [InsertionMark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.insertionmark?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) in WinUI3/UWP?

The function should be able to retrieve the place(index) in a ListView where an object is dropped.
[image]

In this image I'm dragging an item from List2 to List1.

Comment: Architecture between Winforms & XAML frameworks such as UWP/WinUI3 is very different. You can use DragItemsStarting and DragItemsCompleted events https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398742/uwp-listview-drag-and-drop

Comment: Thanks for the example, but my question is about the destination index - the index from the list where the item is copied to. Not about the indexes from where the items are taken.

Comment: There's no concept of "index" here, you can only get the item which led to generating a XAML control.

Comment: There must be, as you can see in the image I added, the UI creates a space for the item that will be added, so the UI somehow knows that there could be added a new item.

Comment: ListView (which is an ItemsControl) understands an enumeration. The index is only related to what (XAML component) contains it using ItemsControl.IndexFromContainer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.indexfromcontainer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WinUI-Gallery](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/dc932c4777c598e2362079a09bdea5b3ced0d65a/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/ListViewPage.xaml.cs#L153) sample shows a workaround, which finds the index based on the calculation of the coordinate of the dragged item and item height.

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks!