# Auto vertical scrolling when dragging listview item near bottom of scrollable listview

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I have yet to find an answer near what I am looking for online for this feature.

Within a Scroll Viewer, I have multiple list views with items within them. I can drag items from one list view to another.

I want to be able to be dragging an item near the bottom of the scroll viewer and have it auto scroll down so I can drop the item in a list view that isn't visible.

Yes, I can scroll with my mouse, but unfortunately, the end use wants to be able to just hold the item at the bottom to scroll down too.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

I am using WINUI3.

[image]

Comment: Use [ScrollViewer.ChangeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.changeview?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4) to scroll from code and determine when to scroll according to the position of dragged items to the bottom of the ScrollViewer, for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/77406535 or add new up down buttons which will scroll the ScrollViewer when hovered over.